# Multiple argument wildcard matches for sudoers file?

Tags: sudo

I'm trying to figure out how to create an entry in the sudoer where I allow a limited set of arguments some optional but have the command still very restrictive.

Is there any easy way to limit these restrictions?

I'd like the user to be able to run with the -w flag and optional value but still be restrictive. I don't want to hardcode values for the -w option. The user should be able to run any of these commands with 10 being any digit.

```
/usr/bin/iptables -nvL *
/usr/bin/iptables -w -nvL *
/usr/bin/iptables -w 10 -nvL *
```

I came up with these 4 entries. Is there a better way to have optional values defined?

```
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables -nvL *
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables -w -nvL *
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables -w [[\:digit\:]] -nvL *
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables -w [[\:digit\:]][[\:digit\:]] -nvL *
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I fear not :/
If you don't want to use wildcards like »?« or even »*«, you'll have to provide quite exactly, what you want.

According to sudoers' man page, it only provides general wildcards:

```
Wildcards
  sudo allows shell-style wildcards (aka meta or glob characters) to be used in host names,
  path names and command line arguments in the sudoers file.  Wildcard matching is done via the
  glob(3) and fnmatch(3) functions as specified by IEEE Std 1003.1 (“POSIX.1”).

  *         Matches any set of zero or more characters (including white space).

  ?         Matches any single character (including white space).

  [...]     Matches any character in the specified range.

  [!...]    Matches any character not in the specified range.

  \x        For any character ‘x’, evaluates to ‘x’.  This is used to escape special characters
            such as: ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’, and ‘]’.

  NOTE THAT THESE ARE NOT REGULAR EXPRESSIONS.
  Unlike a regular expression there is no way to match one or more characters within a range.
```

Answer (score 9):

As others have indicated what you want is not supported by `sudo`, it only supports a generic wildcard.

There are some serious dangers in using wildcards with the `sudo`ers format. For example if you allow `rm -Rf /some/path/*` then you could `sudo rm -Rf /some/path/blarg /another/not/allowed/path` and it would allow them to essentially `rm` any file as long as they also used that path. Similarly you can abuse relative pathing, you could still only delete another path while leaving the specified directory intact via `rm -Rf /some/path/../../../../some/path/that/should/be/restricted`.

You might consider using a "proxy" script which does your input validation.

I highly recommend reading through the whole series of posts but if not at least the ones on wildcards: https://blog.compass-security.com/2012/10/dangerous-sudoers-entries-part-4-wildcards/

Comment: Note that a forward slash (‘/’) will not be matched by wildcards used in the path name. This is to make a path like:
/usr/bin/*
match /usr/bin/who but not /usr/bin/X11/xterm

Comment: As I understand it this is true for the path but not the command itself.